# Hadoop Chart Output (only on final output value)

Tags: java, hadoop, charts

I am doing Hadoop java for my project. I am able to view the output for two company (Total of 2 data columns in the CSV file) displaying in the TextArea. However when I try to display the output in my chart. I am only able to view the chart for the second company.

```
for (Text value : values) {
            String emotion = value.toString();
            switch (emotion){
                case "Super Happy": 
                    one++;
                    break;
                case "Very Happy":
                    two++;
                    break;
                case "Quite Happy":
                    three++;
                    break;
                case "Neutral":
                    four++;
                    break;
                case "Quite Angry":
                    five++;
                    break;
                case "Very Angry":
                    six++;
                    break;
                case "Super Angry":
                    seven++;
                    break;
            }


        context.write(new Text("Company:" + key),
                new Text("\nSuper Happy: " + one + "\n" + "Very Happy: " + two + "\n"
                        + "Quite Happy: " + three + "\n" + "Neutral: " + four + "\n" + "Quite Angry: "
                        + five + "\n" + "Very Angry: " + six + "\n" + "Super Angry: "
                        + seven + "\n\n"));



        MainFrame.dcd.addValue(one, key, "Super Happy");
        MainFrame.dcd.addValue(two, key, "Very Happy");
        MainFrame.dcd.addValue(three, key, "Quite Happy");
        MainFrame.dcd.addValue(four, key, "Neutral");
        MainFrame.dcd.addValue(five, key, "Quite Angry");
        MainFrame.dcd.addValue(six, key, "Very Angry");
        MainFrame.dcd.addValue(seven, key, "Super Angry");

        MainFrame.setTextArea("Company:" + key+"\nSuper Happy: " + one + "\n" + "Very Happy: " + two + "\n"
                + "Quite Happy: " + three + "\n" + "Neutral: " + four + "\n" + "Quite Angry: "
                + five + "\n" + "Very Angry: " + six + "\n" + "Super Angry: "
                + seven + "\n");


        counter++;
    }
```

Expected result should show two different charts, but I only manage to get output charts for the second one.